# issues using parameter queries

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to switch come of my SQL queries to parameter queries but i keep getting some errors shown after the code below:

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid)
        {
            //Define data objects
            SqlConnection conn;
            //SqlCommand comm;
            //Read the connection string from web config
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["clientsConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            //Initialize the connection
            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


            //Create Command
           // comm = new SqlCommand();
            const string SQL = "insert into request (Surname,[Other Names], mobileno, date, email, faculty, dept, [Registration Number], session, thesis, yearGrad, tellerno, amount, address, question ) values (@Surname,[@Other Names],@mobileno,@date, @email, @faculty, @dept, [@Registration Number], @session,@thesis, @yearGrad, @tellerno, @amount, @address,@question)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SQL, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Surname", lblSurname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Other Names]", lblOtherNames.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobileno", lblPhone.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", lblDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", lblEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@faculty", lblFaculty.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dept", lblDept.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[Registration Number]", lblRegNo.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@session", lblSession.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@thesis", lblThesis.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearGrad", lblGradYr.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tellerno", lblTeller.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", lblAmount.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", lblAdd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@question", lblQue.Text);

            conn.Open();

            // verify if the ID entered by the visitor is numeric
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conn.Close();
            //reload page if query executed succesfully
            Response.Redirect("thanks.aspx");
        }
    }
```

Error message is:

> Server Error in '/TranscriptReloaded' Application.
>   Incorrect syntax near 'nvarchar'.
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@date".

Comment: It would be customary to accept the answer if it fixes your problem ! (the tick on the left, under the number!)

Answer (score 3):

"date" is a SQL reserved word, so the translation to SQL may be having a problem with it.  Generally speaking you should avoid using the word date on its own as column names or as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would start by losing the `@[two word]` variable names (which you also use as `[@two word]` elsewhere). I don't know if this is the cause, but I have never seen this usage personally, and I'm dubious. Fine for *column* names (and table names), but variables? Not so sure. Changing the variable names is local to this code, so shouldn't cause any side-effects.

Comment: tx guys, the date was not the problem, Marc was right about how the variable names were declared, i changed them to single names and it worked.